# What is the Shapely value for a weighted majority game?

Tags: game-theory

For a weighted majority game of 4 players with

$$
\begin{array}  & I & II & III & IV \\10 & 30 & 30 & 40  \end{array}
$$

shares, how would I find the Shapley value? Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to derive a weighted majority game and how to get the Shapley value is explained in the following post

[Shapley value for voting games](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310344/calculating-shapley-value-on-voting-game/1310501#1310501)

Assuming now a majority voting with $56$ votes, the Shapley value distributes

$sh_{v}=(0,1,1,1)/3,$

for instance. Changing the quorum to pass a bill may change the distribution of the Shapley value.