# Calculating the Shapley Value on Voting Game

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

In a given country, a new law is adopted if either: $(a)$ Strictly more than one half of the parliament members votes for it and the president approves it or  $(b)$ strictly more then $\frac{2}{3}$ of the parliament members votes for it, without the presidential approval.

Now suppose that the members of parliament are organized in $4$ different parties $A, B, C$ and $D$ with $185, 120, 110$ and $35$ votes, respectively. Where all members of one party cast the same votes. Consider a coalitional game with $5$ players (that is, these $4$ parties and the president $P$).

> How do I find the **Core** and the **Shapley value**? And also is the game supera-dditive or Super-modular ?

Given a coalition game $(N,v)$, I understand that we can compute the shapley value of player $i$ with the formular $$\phi_i (N,v)=\frac{1}{N!} \sum_{S\subseteq N \setminus \{i\}} |S|! (|N|-|S|-1)! \bigg [ v(S \cup \{ i\}) - v(S) \bigg ]$$ But I am having trouble on how to approach this game. Please any hint or help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do have glanced through the following post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310344/calculating-shapley-value-on-voting-game/1310501#1310501 ? Let me give you the following hints: The Shapley value of the first game is $(1,1,1,0)/3$, and for the second it is $(7,3,1,1)/12$. The second game has a veto player, therefore it has a core, whereas the first has an empty core.

Comment: Thank you for the Hint @HolgerI.Meinhardt what got me confuse here is that we have 5 players in the game. (4 parties and the President inclusive)

Comment: This confuses me too! Has he just one vote or more? Is he a new veto player or not? Nothing is specified at all, therefore it is for me not possible to see from this information how the new $5$-person voting game should be defined.

Comment: Yeah exactly, The president have some power to adopt a law if  he gets half of the parliament's vote and his vote too, from condition $(a)$

Comment: OK, now I understand. Like the US-Senate, where the president has the power to adopt a law, if there is a draw. Not quite obvious for a non US-citizen.

Comment: Doesn't it work to pretend that the president has 74 votes and require 300 votes to pass?  (I.e., the presidential `votes' don't change the 2/3 computation.)  If the president approves, then 226 parliamentary votes are needed to pass.  If the president does not approve, then 300 parliamentary votes are needed.